# Data from Collection is missing from database (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

For simplicity and testing, i'm doing this from a new project and then apply it to my actual project once i understand the problem.

I made a model, named **Person**, which contains a List property, named **ServiceNeeded**. Users in the front end may encode as much string of services as they wish, so the input field for **ServiceNeeded** is dynamically created. In the POST method, those string input binds as expected. I save the **Person** object into the database, and works as expected. When I try to retrieve the people objects from the database, all but **ServicesNeeded** are present.

Here are my codes

Model (Person.cs):

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid  Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public List<String> ServiceNeeded { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        this.ServiceNeeded = new List<String>();
    }
}
```

Controller(Index and [POST]Create methods):

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var x = db.People.ToList();
        return View(db.People.ToList());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,ServiceNeeded")] Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            person.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            db.People.Add(person);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(person);
    }
```

As I said the input fields for ServicesNeeded are dynamically create but properly bind to the model.

Here are some screenshots during runtime:

After user do some input:
[image]

The I added a variable before Index returns the View to check in runtime:
[image]

As seen, the same **Person** is present and everything but **ServicesNeeded**. I am fairly new with ASP.NET MVC and web development in general. I do handle other collections in my project, although are collection of objects. Only this particular case I do not understand. Where could my error be?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the dbcontext to load the references if lazy loading is not enabled.

First change `ServiceNeeded` to a virtual property

```
public virtual List<String> ServiceNeeded { get; set; }
```

then load the property when you pull down the person by using `Include`

```
var x = db.People.Include("ServiceNeeded").ToList();
return View(x);
```

Article on loading related entities https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the reply sir. I made the modification as you suggested but that didn't seem to have fixed my problem. when I add "Include" I am getting this error : 

Additional information: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'WebApplication3.Models.Person' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'ServiceNeeded'. I'm also trying the different approaches in loading but no progress so far.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the database; are the records there?  I think the issue is that the ServicesNeeded collection is not persisted to the database; try adding:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,ServiceNeeded")] Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            person.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            db.People.Add(person);

            foreach (var service in person.ServicesNeeded)
                 db.ServicesNeeded.Add(service);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(person);
    }
```

I'm don't believe the relationships attached to the Person object auto-persist on SaveChanges(), and are probably not making it to the database.

Comment: Thank you for the reply sir but if I understood your approach, i'd have to make a separate table just for the string of services. As much as possible I am trying to avoid that case.

Comment: You have to save them somewhere, where are you saving them?  Or the issue is you aren't saving them; you don't need another table, but add a string column to the Person object, and then when saving to DB, concatenate the values separated by a | or something else, and then split them when you load them.  However, I would advise you to be careful about adding custom properties to EF generated entities, which are not properties loaded by EF, because you may encounter errors as you can't use those properties in LINQ and other operations with EF throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best idea that suits Entity Frame work is to create another `Model` for your 'ServiceNeeded', add it to your 'DbContext', save any services in the corresponding `DbSet` and retrieve them using `.Include` in `LINQ`. After this lengthy introduction look at the following codes:
**In your Models:**

```
public class MyService{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string ServiceName {get;set;}
    public Guid PersonId {get;set;}
}
public class Person
{
    public Guid  Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<MyService> ServiceNeeded { get; set; }
}
```

**In your ApplicationDbContext:**

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyService> MyServices { get; set; }
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
```

**In your POST ActionResult:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,ServiceNeeded")] Person person, List<String> ServiceNeeded)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        db.People.Add(person);
        db.SaveChanges();
        db.Entry(person).GetDatabaseValues();
         foreach (string service in ServiceNeeded){
             db.MyServices.Add( new MyService {ServiceName = service,
                   PersonId = person.Id})
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(person);
}
```

Please note that I removed `person.Id = Guid.NewGuid();` so that the `Id`
 be generated by **Database Identity** and then I re-get the `person.Id` so that I create the `MyService` record.

**and finally as @JamieD77 suggested, in your GET ActionResult:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var x = db.People.Include("ServiceNeeded").ToList();
    return View(x);
}
```